# How to view xml code of a list view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have created a view of list by following manner

- Created a new page
- Opened the page in edit mode
- clicked on **add a web part**
- Chose **List and Libraries**
- Clicked on list that is already created.

I want to view the xml code of list view that i have created in share point designer 2010 or web browser (Is it possible ?)

Can anyone help please, i am new to share point.

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/15169/627 ?

Answer (score 10):

**Use the following URL to get XML of list:-**

```
http://{0}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={1}&XMLDATA=TRUE

{0} – The URL to your site.  This could be the root web or a child site.

{1} – The GUID for your list.
```

To find the GUID for a list, just go to the Settings page for the list and copy it from the URL.

**Use the following URL to get XML of list view:**

In addition to viewing a list using the `Cmd=Display` command in the URL request, you can also return all data for a SharePoint list, but based on a specific view from that list, by adding the `&View={ViewGuid}` to the URL request, like the following:

```
http://{yoursite}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={list GUID}&View={ViewGuid}&XMLDATA=TRUE

where: {ViewGuid} : is the GUID of the list view.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
I did n't except the answer this much faster.